# Something like JsFiddle for VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

Is there an online tool for testing VBScript snippet? Something similar jsFiddle for javascript

Comment: VBFiddle.net does this. Use JSfiddle.net to share your VBScript code and instruct people to copy and paste the code to VBFiddle.net to run it.

Comment: http://VBFiddle.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PractiCode](http://www.landofcode.com/online-code-editor.php) supports VBScript (only in Internet Explorer of course) but isn't as user friendly as jsFiddle.

Comment: This works for FREE BASIC ... https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-freebasic-online/

Comment: I don't think PractiCode works. In my case it just copies the code to the results!